# How to combine results from a JOIN with another result set?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables, `CLIENTS` and `MEMBERS`. We are trying to get the member's address from the `CLIENTS` table and all the records from the `MEMBERS` table where the `ID` from `MEMBERS`  matches the `ID` from `CLIENTS`.

At the same time, we would also like to show the rest of the member's info from the `MEMBERS` table where the `ID` is either `NULL` or doesn't exist in the `CLIENTS` table.

I thought the following query would do it, but it isn't getting all the records from `MEMBERS` tables:

```
SELECT c.ID
      ,m.ID
      ,m.fname
      ,m.lname
      ,m.address
      ,m.city
      ,m.state
      ,m.zip

 from Client c
inner join members m on c.id = m.id

UNION ALL

select '',m.* from members m

where m.id IS NULL or m.id NOT IN (select ca.id from clients ca)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What  records are being excluded?

Comment: No record is being excluded. Atleast, that was not the intent. We are trying to add addresses to the clients who have IDs on MEMBERS table and those IDs match up with IDs on CLIENTS table. At the same time, we still want to keep the records of clients who either don't have ID (where ID is null) or they do have IDs but those IDs are only on MEMBERS table but not on CLIENTS table. Thanks a lot

Comment: You said in the original question `it isn't getting all the records` - what is it not returning that it should be?

Comment: First, it is returning all the records where IDs from MEMBERS table match IDs from CLIENTS table. However, there are IDs FROM MEMBERS that are NOT in CLIENTS table that are not getting returned. NOt sure why. Moreover, when the ISNULL part of the query, I still get same results

Comment: Those cases will be covered in your second query though.  You may need to post some sample data for this.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh - I think you have just re-invented the `outer join` anyway but what if you try changing the end of your query to `NOT IN (select ca.id from clients ca WHERE ca.id IS NOT NULL)`. Do you get correct results then?

Comment: Hi Martin. I believe your nice code below gave me what I was looking for. It didn't occur to me that LEFT OUTER JOIN would have solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something it appears that you just need an `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT COALESCE(c.ID, '') AS ID,
       m.ID,
       m.fname,
       m.lname,
       m.address,
       m.city,
       m.state,
       m.zip
FROM   members m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Client c
         ON c.id = m.id
```

With respect to the issue in your question do you have any `NULL` values for `id` in the `Clients` table? That is often the cause of unexpected `NOT IN` behaviour.